# Does Kotlin coroutine runs in the same process where the application live?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to kotlin coroutine, I need to know how kotlin coroutine manage its threading work internally.

> Does it uses separate thread for each task ?
>
> Does kotlin coroutine stays in the same process where the application
>   live ?
>
> Does kotlin coroutine change the process during any intermediate task
>   ?

Comment: Coroutine creates reusable threads from CommonPool, max number of thread it can use is based on Dispatcher, for instance Dispatchers.IO can execute tasks max on 64 threads by default. Other dispatcher can reuse these as well. Dispatchers.Default has max number of threads same as real threads in your processor.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by process.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu i mean the group of thread contain in a process. so each process has n thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Coroutine uses a thread pool to run tasks.

So we can say as the point of Coroutine users' view each task will run on a separate thread but under the hood, it's just a thread pool.

And for the process yes. It's in the same process as the application is.